# PHP Flock Writing to Open File

Tags: php, fopen, flock, fclose

I have a php script that logs ads(banners) for a website and stores them to a .dat file.  Inside this file an ID, URL, an other important information is saved.  The problem I am having is that there are at any given time 4 ads on the page and so the .dat file is often corrupted when the php script attempts to write to it while it is open.
I checked and tried this solution however it did not help me:
[PHP Simultaneous file access / flock() issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168724/php-simultaneous-file-access-flock-issue/9176384#9176384)

The function I am using at the moment looks like this:

```
function writeads(){
    global $bannerAdsPath, $ads, $bannerAds;
    $data = fopen($bannerAdsPath, 'w') or die();
    flock($data, 2) or die();
    fputs($data, @join("\n", $ads)."\n");
    while (list ($key, $val) = each ($bannerAds)) {
        if (($key != '') && ($val != '')) {
            fputs($data, $key.'='.$val."\n");
        }
    }
    flock($data, 3);
    fclose($data);
    reset($bannerAds);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have been scratching my head over this for a while.
Side bit of information, the client did not want to have their code rewritten to use a Database instead of a file so that option is out.

Thanks!

Comment: Please use the constants `LOCK_EX` and `LOCK_UN`. This improves readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost never want to use `flock` to unlock a file; just use `fclose`; the file will be unlocked when the handle is closed, and that way you know that no buffered writes will happen after you unlock.

Comment: The implicit unlock doesn't happen any more since PHP-5.3.2. Furthermore this is not OP's issue. The implicit truncate of `fopen()` in mode `w` is causing the corruption.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch the implicit unlock *does* happen; it's just done by the OS instead of PHP doing an unnecessary and wrong `flock(..., LOCK_UN)` on its own.

Comment: True, it does happen. But I still don't see how your answer fits OP's issue.

Answer (score 2):

fopen with 'w' truncates the file before you have the option of flocking it.